# Modifying object sent through Intent with Parcelable

Tags: java, android

I'm currently sending objects between activities through intent. I'm using Parcelable interface.

It seems like the second activity that picks up the object is the NEW instance of the object that gets passed in.

For example, in firstActivity.class, I have

```
foo f = new foo();
Intent i = new Intent(context, secondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("foo", f);
startActivity(i);
```

In my secondActivity.class, I have

```
foo f = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("foo");
f.setName("a");
```

Then when I go back to firstActivity.class, I do

```
f.getName(); // returns null
```

Question is: How to I pass the same object between activities, so I can modify its data in different activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parcelable` interface provides a way to serialize data from your class and recreate it somewhere else. That means that using `Parcelable` will always result in creation of a new instance when you read it from somewhere (from `Bundle` for instance).

If you need to return your `Parcelable` back you could use activity results to send the new object you created and updated, but I would advise against that. This is too much work for something as simple as you need.

You could share an object between these 2 activities by holding it somewhere not attached to lifecycle of these activities (in `Application` or any kind of a [singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/).

For instance:

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Activity1:

```
Singleton.INSTANCE.setFoo(new Foo());
```

Activity2:

```
Singleton.INSTANCE.getFoo().setName("a");
```

Activity1:

```
Singleton.INSTANCE.getFoo().getName(); // Should be "a" now
```

This way should not be used if you need to persist this name, since it will be cleared as soon as system kills the app (for any reason, it can happen when app is in background). In that case some kind of database should be used.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Singleton was what I was thinking too, but I just thought maybe there are other ways to pass objects around. I do have a database, but I just want a data structure to use when data is loading into my app. I appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Did you consider using https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?
Although, that may not be useful in your case, since you have two separate activities...

If you want to avoid some kind of a "bridge" between these 2 activities (which has to be either DB or some kind of a shared object), I think you would have to use activity results. That also means that your first activity would not be updated whenever you change that object, but only when you set result on second activity and then read it in the first.

Comment: I think I can manipulate the ViewModel. So I can treat every activity as "first activity", and just use the data in ViewModel to update the next activity. But I think Singleton approach is just easier and faster